# React Native offline location sharing app

Tags: react-native

I need to build an app so that I can share location with friends. My approach first was to get location access and share it via Firebase but this doesn't fulfill the requirement of offline access.
I've already worked on bridging in RN. Kindly suggest possible solutions. I've already done a bit of research but couldn't find any satisfying answer/solution.

Comment: How can you share location if you're offline?

Comment: This question is too broad, but technology wise, you probably want to track their position locally and use Project Thali to send

Comment: @JamesZ google location works offline. I was wondering if there was any way to get gps data of another person.

Comment: @JamesZ from "offline", I mean when user isn't connected to internet.

Comment: And what do you mean with sharing? How does that work if you're not online.

Answer (score 0):

you can send your loction through sms using smsmanager
just get your longitude and latitude and concatinate the link send it through sms its the only way to send or through your current location offline...